# Загрузка файла на сайт Python с помощью requests. post

Tags: python, requests

Возникла необходимость в отправке файлов на сервер средствами Python через post

```
url = 'https://exempl.com/downloads'
```

Ниже по сути два одинаковых куска кода, но работают с разной скоростью.
Почему если по сути одно и тоже

1-й загружает якобы файл 300 мб за 1 сек

```
  with open(filename, "rb") as upload_file:  
    payload = MultipartEncoder({'preview': upload_file})
    headers = {'Content-Type': payload.content_type}
    response = requests.post(url, data=filename, headers=headers)
```

2й загружает 300 мб 2 минуты тот же файл

```
 with open(filename, "rb") as upload_file:  
    payload = MultipartEncoder({'preview': upload_file})
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers={'Content-Type': 
    payload.content_type})
```

проверить загрузку файла временно не могу,но даже при первом варианте приходит ответ 200.За секунду 300 мегабайт?

Вот весь код:

```
 with open(filename, "rb") as upload_file:  
    payload = MultipartEncoder({'preview': upload_file})
    headers = {'Content-Type': payload.content_type}
    response = requests.post(url, data=filename, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Код ответа в response проверяли? Может там ошибка приходит, поэтому и быстро завершается.

Comment: @insolor -так я же написал.приходит ответ 200.Но 300 метров за секунду.как?

Comment: Поправьте код в вопросе, чтобы он совпадал с кодом у вас. Сейчас в одном месте пропущена кавычка, в другом - лишний перенос строки, в итоге такое вообще не запустится.

Comment: @insolor - готово.Вот код который за секунду отправляет 300 метров.

Comment: Приведите оба варианта код полностью, а то краткие фрагменты отличаются только именами new_filename и payload. Я подозреваю, что в "медленном" варианте вы upload_file напрямую передаете, но все же лучше если вы все детали дополните, а не нужно было догадываться. MultipartEncoder из requests-toolbelt берете, правильно?

Comment: @insolor - привел.по сути они отличаются только headers .А скорость первого 1 сек а второго 2 мин.Почему мне не ясно.

Comment: `response = requests.post(url, data=filename, headers=headers)` - ну так вы имя файла вместо самого файла передаете

Comment: @insolor-понял.спасибо.а проверить передалось или нет я смогу только когда получу доступ к хостингу?

Comment: Скорее всего да. Если сервер сам по себе не дает каким-то образом получить доступ к загруженному файлу.